# popup menu submenu title color

Tags: android, popup, android-support-library, popupmenu

I'm using `PopUp Menu` in my application. One of the items in my popup menu has three sub menu, like

1. SetAs

   - ringtone
   - notification
   - alarm
2. Item2
3. Item3

.

After clicking on "SetAs" item, I was just seeing the three sub items and nothing else. I was using an old version of support library, something like `v22`,or `v23`, I'm not sure. But when I updated android support library to `v7:25.4.0` in my project I saw a title(SetAs) is showing in the sub menu view.

This is a screenshot of my popup menu:

[image: screenshot]

Now my question is how can I change the color of this title?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've done this programmatically with below code:

Put this before you call `popup.show()`.

```
// Change PopupMenu subMenu title color
PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(activity, view);
Menu itemSetAs = popup.getMenu();
SubMenu s = itemSetAs.findItem(R.id.SetAs).getSubMenu();
SpannableString headerTitle = new SpannableString(itemSetAs.findItem(R.id.SetAs).getTitle());

// Change the color: 
headerTitle.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.YOUR_COLOR), 0, headerTitle.length(), 0);

// You can even change the size:
int textSize = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.your_size);
headerTitle.setSpan(new AbsoluteSizeSpan(textSize), 0, headerTitle.length(), SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);

s.setHeaderTitle(headerTitle);

popup.show().
```